# read comment or commented node from xml in swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift2, osx-elcapitan

First, consider a xml structure like below:

```
<!-- this is a comment -->
<methods>
                <include name="test" />
                <include name="test" />
<!--            <include name="testcase-commented" />-->
<!--            <include name="testcase-commented" />-->
<!--            <include name="testcase-commented" />-->
                <include name="test" />
</methods>
```

From this xml i can read all the included name using NSXmlParser.

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    if(elementName == "include"){

        testCaseName.append(attributeDict["name"]!)
    }
}
```

But the commented test cases are not parsed using this method.

Is there any way to read only the commented testcase name from xml using the xml parser or this is not possible to read the commented tag from xml in swift?

No solution found over the net.

I am using

```
xcode 7.3 OSX 10.11 and swift 2.2
```

Comment: The whole point of comments is to be able to put in data that has no semantic meaning. Why would you want to parse them?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov thanks  for the interest, yes i know that i can store in a file that has no semantic meaning. But my requirements are like that .... have to know the commented test case name.

Comment: Well then you're probably on your own, because what you're desire is essentially no longer XML. You'll probably have to write your own parser. Again, I would advise changing the design to not require this. Perhaps instead of commenting out test-cases, give them an attribute like `ignore="true"`.

Comment: thanks again, but add ignore="true" to 20 or more test case one by one is annoying i think. some time i need to run 20 test case or some time more or some time less

Comment: Use a texteditor that support regex find/replace to replace `<!--(\s*<include.*)(/>\s*)-->` with `$1ignore="true"$2`, and boom, all your comments are converted to attributed non-comments

Comment: nop....i don't want that ... is this possible using swift xml parser....thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120138/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-noor).

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov check the chat

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov got solution, you can put it in answer....thanks

Comment: done, please rate/accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i want to thanks AlexanderMomchliov for his great suggestion and I hope you know how to parse a xml file.

parser has some overloaded methods, from there, just call this:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundComment comment: String) {

    print(comment)
}
```

if the xml file is has some commented node like:

```
<!-- this is a comment -->
<test name="testOne">
<classes>
    <class name="TestClassOne">
        <methods>
            <include name="test_480" />
<!--                <include name="test_481" />-->
<!--                <include name="test_482" />-->
        </methods>
    </class>
</classes>
</test>
```

Than the output will be like:

```
this is a comment
<include name="test_481" />
<include name="test_482" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the [`parser(_:foundComment:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser:foundComment:) method in your `NSXMLParserDelegate` to be notified when comments are found.

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundComment comment: String) {
    print(comment)
}
```